# Cómo guardar latitud y longitud de Google Maps en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-maps

Tengo un cuadro de texto donde busco direcciones con el autocompletado de `google maps api` y después asigno el valor de la dirección, latitud y longitud a otros cuadros pero cuando mando el scope `ng-model` de los datos no manda nada:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Direccion</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="txtautocomplete"  placeholder="Direccion">
     <input type="text" id="texto" ng-model="direccion" class="form-control" >
     <input type="text" id="latitud" ng-model="latitud" class="form-control" >
     <input type="text" id="longitud" ng-model="longitud" class="form-control" >
</div>   


<script type="text/javascript">
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', intilize);
  function intilize() 
  {
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById("txtautocomplete"));
      google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      var location = place.formatted_address;
      var latitud= place.geometry.location.lat();
      var longitud=place.geometry.location.lng();
      document.getElementById('lblresult').innerHTML = location;
      document.getElementById('texto').value=location;
      document.getElementById('latitud').value=latitud;
      document.getElementById('longitud').value=longitud;
    });
  };

</script>
```

Lo único que ocupo es obtener la latitud, longitud y la dirección para guardarlos en una `base de datos`.

Answer (score 1):

Bueno viendo tu código no he visto por ningún lado que estés capturando los valores de los `inputs`, tampoco, veo el uso de un controller, osea no veo que este usando angular, de la forma que yo hago es la siguiente:

```js
angular.module('mapsApp', [])
  .controller('datosMapa_Ctrl', datosMapa_Ctrl);

datosMapa_Ctrl.$inject = ['$scope'];

function datosMapa_Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.capturarDatos = function() {
    var Latitud, Longitud;

    Latitud = $scope.latitud;
    Longitud = $scope.longitud;

    alert(Latitud + " " + Longitud);

  }



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='mapsApp' ng-controller="datosMapa_Ctrl">
  <input type="text" id="latitud" ng-model="latitud" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" id="longitud" ng-model="longitud" class="form-control">
  <button ng-click="capturarDatos()">Presionar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: pero con eso tienes que ponerle los datos manualmente mientras k con la api puedes mandarlos traer y asignarselos a un texto o label 
pero a la hora de hacerles scope no manda el valor

Comment: Es que lo que te mostre es como capturar los datos, quizas es lo que tu estabas preguntando, por que dijiste que no estaban mostrando, eso entendi, debes de mirar es la forma como los capture